# Accessing remote controller signal strength in Mobile SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to develop an iOS app using the DJI Mobile SDK that would interact with my Phantom 4.

I'd like my app to display the signal strength of the remote controller in the SDK (as is displayed in the DJI GO app). The `DJIRCInfo` class contains a `signalQuality` field which corresponds to the signal quality of a connected master or slave remote controller, but the Phantom 4 apparently doesn't support master/slave mode (the `isMasterSlaveModeSupported` returns `False`).

How would I go about accessing the RC's signal strength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DJIAirlink` object represents the link between aircraft and remote controller.

There is a delegate method [`-lbAirLink:didUpdateRemoteControllerSignalInformation:`](https://developer.dji.com/iframe/mobile-sdk-doc/ios/Protocols/DJILBAirLinkDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)DJILBAirLinkDelegate(im)lbAirLink:didUpdateRemoteControllerSignalInformation:)that will give you the signal strength for light bridge based links.

Comment: I averaged the signal strengths of the 2 RC antennas to output a global signal strength though I feel that might be a bit clumsy - is there anything in the SDK that combines signal strengths automatically?